# Creating new Branch under master, showing already existing commit under newly created branch

Tags: git, github, version-control, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

When i am creating new branch using `create branch` option on bitbucket, it is creating successfully.

But when i go on commits option and choose newly created branch from dropdown under heading `COMMITS`..it is showing few commits for that new branch.

How it is possible to have commit when branch is new.

Please help me guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commits displayed are onthe branch which you create the new branch from. Assume you create `newBranch` from `master`, the structure like:

```
A---B---C  master
         \
          D newBranch
```

so the commits shows

```
D
C
B
A
```

If you want to show the commits from `newBranch`, you can view in **Branches** Tab, select the branch and view the commits in **Commits** Tab.

[image]

Comment: thats work for me. i was looking into my newly created branch from COMMIT option. thats why getting commits under it. Your solution was explanatory. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Choose the branch you want to start from (master) and than as you did before create branch from this point.

Another option is to use the command line:

```
# checkout master
git checkout master

# create new branch out of master
git checkout -b <newB>

# push the new branch to the remote
git push origin newB
```